# Gitlab Repository to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, gitlab

I have Laravel project at Gitlab repository and I want to connect it with Heroku. Is it possible to connect them even if the Heroku server is only a free subscription?

When I have new commits on Gitlab, I want it updates the Heroku server.
If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible. Things needed:

1. Php and Laravel knowledge
2. Heroku user account
3. Git

For details you can follow any below link

https://appdividend.com/2018/04/17/how-to-deploy-laravel-project-on-heroku/

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

https://medium.com/@sdkcodes/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-app-to-heroku-24b5cb33fbe

Comment: It'd be better to include relevant details in your answer instead of referring to links. Your answer boils down to "yes", which isn't much of an answer. You can use links for additional reading or to cite sources, but your answer should be complete and self-contained here. Thanks!